# Selenium WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10)) launches; java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I have installed Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0), Chrome Driver ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.134, Chrome Version: 103.0.5060.134, Selenium: 4.3.0, I have the following imports and the portion of code that returns error on Chrome Driver:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocatorFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;

public void enterUsr(String user)  {

    WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10), Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebElement inputUsr =  myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("username")));
    inputUsr.sendKeys(user);
}
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, java.time.Duration)'
    at Paginas.PageLoginKop.achicarOpcionPolicies(PageLoginKop.java:88)
    at Paginas.PageLoginKop.login(PageLoginKop.java:98)
```

Comment: Any other help? the coded is blocked due to this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have passed 2 arguments as `Duration.ofSeconds(10)`

Remove one of the `Duration.ofSeconds(10)` argument you will be good to go.

You effective line of code will be:

```
WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Optimizing your code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("username"))).sendKeys(user);
```

Comment: This optimization did not work. Still get the same error